# Simple JQuery slider not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new to jQuery and javascript and I am working on some animations to practice my new skills. The following code is a simple slider that cycles through 4 slides with setInterval() and can also be navigated on click. The slider works fine except for when the first or last slide is active and the buttons are clicked. In this case, the slider shows a blank slide before cycling back. I tried to manipulate the ul on click when the margin-left is equal to -2880px, without any success. Here is my code:

```js
var i = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
  $("#my-slider").animate({"margin-left": "-=720px"}, 1000, function(){
     i++; 
     if( i === 4 ) {
          i = 0; 
           $("#my-slider").css("margin-left", 0); 
     }
     }); 
    }, 5000); 
  })
  $(document).ready(function() {
$(".right").click(function() {
    $("#my-slider").animate({"margin-left": "-=720px"}, 1000);  
}); 

$(".left").click(function() {
 $("#my-slider").animate({"margin-left": "+=720px"}, 1000); 
   }); 
 });
```

```css
.slider-wrapper {
 width: 50%;
 height: 400px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 overflow: hidden; 
}

.slider-wrapper ul {
 list-style-type: none; 
 width: 3600px;
 max-width: 3600px;
 height: 400px;
 padding: 0; 
 margin: 0; 
}

.slider-wrapper li {
 float: left;
 width: 720px;
 height: 400px; 
}

#slide1 {
background: #04151F; 
}

#slide2 {
 background: #183A37; 
}

#slide3 {
 background: #EFD6AC; 
}

#slide4 {
 background: #C44900;
}

#slide5 {
 background: #04151F; 
}

.left, .right {
 font-size: 40px; 
 z-index: 1;
 position: fixed; 
 float: right; 
 margin: -15% 0 0 0.5%; 
 cursor: pointer;
 color: #FFF;
}

.right {
 margin-left: 47%;   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider-wrapper">
 <ul id="my-slider">
  <li id="slide1"></li>
  <li id="slide2"></li>
  <li id="slide3"></li>
  <li id="slide4"></li>
  <li id="slide5"></li>
 </ul>
 <p class="left">&larr;</p>
 <p class="right">&rarr;</p>
</div>
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: It will be very helpful if you create a fiddle

Comment: @AnoopLL Here is the fiddle :  https://jsfiddle.net/nbLz6zzb/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Think it`s the simplest solution!

> https://jsfiddle.net/nbLz6zzb/1/

```js
var i = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {

  setInterval(function() {
  $("#my-slider").animate({"margin-left": "-=720px"}, 1000, function(){
        i++; 
        if( i === 4 ) {
          i = 0; 
           $("#my-slider").css("margin-left", 0); 
        }
     }); 
    }, 5000); 


/////////////////////////////////////

$(".right").click(function() {
    $("#my-slider").animate({"margin-left": "-=720px"}, 1000, function(){
        i++; 
        if( i === 4 ) {
          i = 1; 
           $("#my-slider").css("margin-left", 0); 
        }
     });    
}); 

$(".left").click(function() {

 if ( $("#my-slider").css("margin-left") <= '720px' && $("#my-slider").css("margin-left") >= '0px') {
  $("#my-slider").animate({"margin-left": "-2880px"}, 1000); 
 } else {
  $("#my-slider").animate({"margin-left": "+=720px"}, 1000); 
 }

   }); 


});
```

```css
.slider-wrapper {
width: 50%;
height: 400px;
margin: 0 auto;
overflow: hidden; 
}

.slider-wrapper ul {
list-style-type: none; 
width: 3600px;
max-width: 3600px;
height: 400px;
padding: 0; 
margin: 0; 
}

.slider-wrapper li {
float: left;
width: 720px;
height: 400px; 
}

#slide1 {
background: #04151F; 
}

#slide2 {
background: #183A37; 
}

#slide3 {
background: #EFD6AC; 
}

#slide4 {
background: #C44900;
}

#slide5 {
background: #04151F; 
}

.left, .right {
font-size: 40px; 
z-index: 1;
position: fixed; 
float: right; 
margin: -15% 0 0 0.5%; 
cursor: pointer;
color: #FFF;
}

.right {
margin-left: 47%;   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider-wrapper">
<ul id="my-slider">
    <li id="slide1"></li>
    <li id="slide2"></li>
    <li id="slide3"></li>
    <li id="slide4"></li>
    <li id="slide5"></li>
</ul>
<p class="left">&larr;</p>
<p class="right">&rarr;</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You are welcome! Thanks for accepting, Appreciate that! My advice: If You want to make very complex animation, don't use Jquery! Use GreenSock Tweenmax js library: http://greensock.com/gsap It is Super easy and powerful for animation. My projects using JS and GreenSock lib: http://codepen.io/smalinux/pen/yJwJjm/left/ http://codepen.io/smalinux/

Comment: Thanks, will check it out :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the code from your cycle for the buttons as well.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".right").click(function() {
    $("#my-slider").animate({"margin-left": "-=720px"}, 1000, function(){
    i++; 
        if( i === 4 ) {
          i = 0; 
           $("#my-slider").css("margin-left", 0); 
        }
  });   
});
```

Comment: Okay this only works for the right button, the left one is more complicated and I have no solution for that right now.